# Play a sound when mutt has new mail?

Tags: email, audio, mutt, procmail

I'm using **mutt** for my mail, usually put on the 2nd monitor with some other windows. Because I'm not monitoring that monitor I often miss the new mails.

I want mutt to play a sound (or use **Growl**) to notify me on new mails. Anyone know about a hook or a command or maybe a **procmail** filter for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`procmail` is an appropriate tool for playing a sound when new mail arrives.

I used to use this `procmail` recipe ...

```
:0c
| /usr/local/bin/wavp full_path_name_to_wav_file >/dev/null
```

Choose an appropriate command line player for the sound file that you wish to play.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to modify or patch mutt to have this functionality as it's not built in. There are other great mail notifiers available though such as [biff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biff), which will do this for you, if you don't mind using a separate program.